# Error linking with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, gcc4

I've try to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#define ARRAY_TAM 2

typedef int (*operacion)(int, int);
typedef const char* (*Pfchar)();

int suma(int, int);
int resta(int, int);

const char* descrSuma();
const char* descrResta();
const char* simbSuma();
const char* simbResta();

class OP
{
    private:

    public:
        operacion op;
        Pfchar descr;
        Pfchar simb;

};

int main (int argv, char *argc[])
{
    OP ArrayOP[ARRAY_TAM];

    ArrayOP[0].op = suma;
    ArrayOP[0].descr = descrSuma;
    ArrayOP[1].op = resta;
    ArrayOP[1].descr = descrResta;

    int op1, op2;
    unsigned int i;
    char opcion;
    bool fin = false;

    while (fin != true)
    {
        cout << "CALCULADORA" << "\n";
        cout << "===========" << "\n";

        for (i = 0; (i < ARRAY_TAM); i++)
        {
            cout << i+1;
            cout << ".- ";
            cout << ArrayOP[i].descr() << "\n";
        }

        cout << i+1 << ".- " << "Salir" << endl;

        cout << "Opcion: ";

        cin >> opcion;
        opcion = atoi(&opcion);
        opcion--;
        cout << (int)opcion << endl;

        if ((opcion >= 0) && (opcion < ARRAY_TAM))
        {
            cout << "Operando 1: ";
            cin >> op1;
            cout << "Operando 2: ";
            cin >> op2;
            cout << "Resultado: op1 " << ArrayOP[opcion].simb()
                         << " op2 = " << ArrayOP[opcion].op(op1, op2);
        }   
        else if (opcion == ARRAY_TAM)
        {
            fin = true;
        }

    }

    return 0;

}


int suma (int op1, int op2)
{return op1 + op2;}

int resta (int op1, int op2)
{return op1 - op2;}

const char* descrSuma()    
{return "Suma";}

const char* descrResta() 
{return "Resta";}

const char* simbSuma()
{return "+";}

const char* simbResta()
{return "-";}
```

An it works, but I have a lot of problems linking with gcc with debbugging symbols and it doesn't link :-(

Need Help!

Large linker error:

> facon@facon-laptop:~/Windows - Mis
>   documentos/Prog/C/Ejercicios/pedirentero$
>   g++ -o main main.o main.o: In function
>   `_start':
>
> /build/buildd/eglibc-2.10.1/csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:65:
>   multiple definition of `_start'
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.10.1/csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:65:
>
> first defined here
>   main.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple
>   definition of `_fp_hw'
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0):
>   first defined here main.o: In function
>   `_fini': (.fini+0x0): multiple
>   definition of`_fini'
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.fini+0x0):
>   first defined here
>   main.o:(.rodata+0x4): multiple
>   definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0):
>   first defined here main.o: In function
>   `__data_start': (.data+0x0): multiple
>   definition of`__data_start'
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.data+0x0):
>   first defined here main.o: In function
>   `__data_start': (.data+0x4): multiple
>   definition of`__dso_handle'
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0):
>   first defined here main.o: In function
>   `_init': (.init+0x0): multiple
>   definition of`_init'
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.init+0x0):
>   first defined here
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0):
>   multiple definition of `**DTOR_END**'
>   main.o:(.dtors+0x4): first defined here
>
> /usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot
>   create .eh_frame_hdr section,
>   --eh-frame-hdr ignored. /usr/bin/ld: error in main.o(.eh_frame); no
>   .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

PD: Edited.

Comment: Please edit your code to remove the unecessary vertical white space. And "a  lot of problems" doesn't give us anything to go on - post the specific error messages you are getting.

Comment: Sorry, I'll do that the next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write "... it works", but then you write "... problems with linking".

I am little bit confused with this question, because:

- If there are problems with linking then it *doesn't work* ...
- But if it works, then you *don't have* problems with linking...

So I guess that you mean: "it compiles, but there are linking errors" ?

If that's the case, then you could try

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o main
```

instead of

```
gcc -g main.cpp -o main
```

EDIT: ... and do **not** mention **main.o** on the command line =;)

EDIT: if that all doesn't help - maybe there is something wrong with your g++/gcc installation?

on ubuntu please try

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

Comment: It do the same at linking, I think, I haven't got the debugging library or something like that.

Comment: what kind of development environment is this? linux? cygwin? mingw?

Comment: which version of Ubuntu? karmic? Is it a 32bit or a 64bit Ubuntu?

Comment: ... and how did you install gcc/g++ ? I would recommend that you use **sudo aptitude install build-essential**

Comment: Karmic Koala 9.10, 32 Bits.
I did that when I started programming in C/C++

Comment: I am using that too. But it works perfectly well here. Have you tried the "sudo aptitude install build-essential' ?

Answer (score 4):

Did you use `gcc` instead of `g++`?

If `gcc` is used with C++ code it will give weird linking errors. C++ code must be compiled with `g++`.

---

**EDIT**: Based on the new information you provided I see that you are running `g++ -o main main.o main.o`.

You should instead run: `g++ -o main main.cpp`

Comment: It do the same with gcc a g++.

Comment: What is the "same"? You never explained exactly what the error is

Comment: I have the same error:

http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-pantalla-3747487.html

Comment: In that screenshot you ran main.o again instead of main.cpp

Comment: Yeah that works but I need to debug it because I have an error in Pointer to function.

I did:

g++ -g main.cpp main.o
g++ -o main main.o

With this I have the error that I posted.

Comment: please do not use: g++ -g main.cpp main.o. That's wrong. use: g++ -g main.cpp -o main